# How to check a function has an exact return-type using Concept?

Tags: c++, function, c++20, return-type, c++-concepts

There's a `std::convertible_to<T>` concept to check whether a result of a call can be converted to a certain type.

But I want to check if a function has an exact return-type. How can I do that?

Comment: Does [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) work for you?

Answer (score 6):

You can write a concept which uses the [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) to check the return type of the function:

Example:

```
#include <concepts> // std::same_as

template<typename FuncType, typename RetType>
concept SameReturn = requires(FuncType func) {
    { func() } -> std::same_as<RetType>;
};

template<typename Callable> requires SameReturn<Callable, int>
auto test(Callable func)
{
    return func();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << test([]() {return 1; });
    // std::cout << test([]() {return "string literals"; }); // error!
    return 0;
}
```

**([See a Live Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eT88E78TM))**